# External 2,5" 2-bay RAID USB3 Enclosure with hdparm/udisksctl power-off support

Tags: linux, data-storage, nas, raid, raid-controller

It's unbelievably hard to find external 2,5" 2-bay RAID enclosures, but apparently it's impossible to find such an enclosure with hdparm/udisksctl support. I just want to spin down and power off the drives in the enclosure from a Linux shell (e.g., udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdb). I already tried ICY BOX IB-RD2253-U31, without success.

Is anybody aware of such an enclosure?

Comment: Have you tried QNAP? They are in the business of RAID NAS and DAS devices so presumably have decent software support.

Comment: Thanks Jan. Yes, I checked that out actually, but they don't offer 2.5" DAS systems. Good idea though :)

Comment: A quick Google has thrown a new product at me https://www.qnap.com/en/product/qda-a2ar introduced in May this year.

Comment: And your info might be outdated: the TR-002 supports 2.5" drives: https://www.qnap.com/en/product/tr-002/specs/hardware

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about their software, but being a company specialising in this presumably QNAP has good software support.

One device which I presume will meet your expectations is the [TR-002](https://www.qnap.com/en/product/tr-002/specs/hardware) which has two 2.5" bays. They even post a test result using 2 x Samsung 850 Pro. Should you be interested there is also [a four drive version](https://www.qnap.com/en/product/tr-004).

**I don't have experience with these devices nor does a quick Google search show anything.** This answer is based on the assumption that QNAP being who they are offers the required software features.